# R program and average result printing

Tags: r, dplyr

In R, using dplyr, I have a data table that has independent variables sex and political party, and dependent variable salary. I can find the average salary of men/women and of Labour vs Tory, but I want the average of Tory men, Tory women, Labour men and Labour women. How can I get that?

I have:
**Labour Tory**

```
Male Female Male Female

£30,000 £27,000 £25,000 £23,000
£26,000 £19,000 £24,500 £27,000
£28,000 £23,000 £26,000 £21,000
£35,000 £22,000 £31,000 £22,000
£35,000 £21,000 £27,000 £30,000
£37,000 £20,000 £30,000 £30,000
```

I need something like:

```
gender party mean(salary)
1 female labour 27833.33
2 female tory 23000.00
3 male labour 27250.00
4 male tory 31166.67
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the complete data set to build a function

but use `aggregate(data = df, salary~gender+party, FUN = mean)`